# windows phone skydrive signin localization

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a WP7 app that accesses SkyDrive. I have  a `SignInButton` with `TextType = 'Signin'`. The text displayed as **'Sign in'** or **'Sign out'**.

Is there any way to localize this for different languages?

Answer (score 0):

All the steps neccessary to accomplish this are described in the MSDN documentation.

Start with [Globalization and Localization for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637522%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to understand the concepts and you'll find the page [How to: Build a Localized Application for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637520%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) that describes your issue.

There's even a complete working code sample `Globalization Sample` located in the [Code Samples for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) page.